# Updating groovy to latest version 2.4.11 causes gmaven build failure

Tags: groovy, gmaven-plugin, gmaven

When I upgraded groovy to latest version 2.4.11 and tried to build maven project I get the below error.

I tried the following:

- Updated pom.xml with dependency of groovy-all-2.4.11 but is seems like gmaven plugin is outdated
- tried using gmaven-plus plugin
- Cannot downgrade groovy below 2.0.x as my code requires it

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5:execute (default) on project xxxxxx: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5:execute failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5:execute: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ModuleNode.getStarImports()Ljava/util/List;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/gmaven-plugin/1.5/gmaven-plugin-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/runtime/gmaven-runtime-api/1.5/gmaven-runtime-api-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/feature/gmaven-feature-api/1.5/gmaven-feature-api-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/runtime/gmaven-runtime-loader/1.5/gmaven-runtime-loader-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/feature/gmaven-feature-support/1.5/gmaven-feature-support-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/runtime/gmaven-runtime-support/1.5/gmaven-runtime-support-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/gshell/gshell-io/2.4/gshell-io-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/1.12/qdox-1.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.2.1/file-management-1.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.1/maven-shared-io-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.4/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-impl/2.0.4.1/maven-reporting-impl-2.0.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.1/plexus-interpolation-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.2.0/commons-validator-1.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.6/commons-digester-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.4/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.4/maven-reporting-api-2.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-site-renderer-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-7/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.7/plexus-velocity-1.1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-decoration-model-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/commons-collections-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-apt/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-module-apt-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-module-fml-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xdoc/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-module-xdoc-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-module-xhtml-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.10/slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/buildapp/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/gossip/gossip/1.2/gossip-1.2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>com.palamida.appsec:palamida-appsec:6.11.2-10-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```